# wkhtmltopdf fails to use font-face properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I used an absolute URI for referencing the font file, but I get this error:

```
Failed to execute:  
../../../bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64    --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0  --orientation 'Portrait' --page-size 'A4' --dpi '300'   -q - -   
Error: PDF could not be generated!
```

Nothing of use for debugging.  I can't install the font locally because I'm on a shared host (meaning I can't avoid using @font-face).  When debugging, the html page renders just fine; when generating the PDF, I get the error.  If I try and embed the font directly using base64 encoding, the font just doesn't get applied (defaults to another font).

Further testing:

It is only when the @font-face rule is being applied that it fails without a reason.  If I set the style media to be "print", no errors - but no font either.  When I set it to "all" and the font is either a) correctly referenced or b) input directly via base64 encoding - it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't wkhtmltopdf's fault - it's webkit's fault.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=468568